# How to send message using nio directly without client send me message firstly

Tags: java, nio

I learn nio now, but I don't know how to send message without client send me message firstly after it connected with server. I try to cache SelectionKey and SocketChannel, but it does'n t work. So how can I solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Can you share your code please.

Comment: How do you connect your client to the server, without sending something, like a acknowledge request?

Comment: Just call `write()`. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, my english is little pool, I saw many examples like this : **key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);**. When client send a message and server deal it over, SelectionKey change to SelectionKey.OP_WRITE and wait to server send message. Now I want to know how can I send message that do not wait the client send me message to change the status first.

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem，there are two methods selectKeys and keys, selectKeys can get all channels that receive an action. keys can get all channels that connect with server, I can use keys method to send message directly.

Comment: You don't need either of those methods to send messages. Just call `write()`. OP_WRITE is only for the times when `write()` *fails* to write the message. There are hundreds of answers here about this.